# Iterated logarithm law for difference (supremum(W) - infimum(W) ) is it 2srt(2/pi) sqrt(t loglog(t))?

Tags: stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

[Law of iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiener_process#Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm) 
says that 
$$\sup(W(t)) \sim \sqrt{2 t \log(\log(t))}.$$

Consider $\sup(W(t)) - \inf(W(t))$ 
my guess based on numerics that it should be
$$2\sqrt{\dfrac 2\pi} \sqrt{t \log(\log(t))}.$$

I guess it should be well-known ?
Can one provide a reference ?

---

Matlab code for numerics

```
len = 1e7
iter = 100
for k=1:iter
    d = randn(1,len);
    v = cumsum(d);
    mx = max(v);
    mn = min(v);
    dt(k,1) = mx-mn;
    dt(k,2) = abs(v(end));
end;

fprintf('Mean(Max - min)/sqrt(len)/(2*sqrt(2/pi)) %f; Mean(Final)/sqrt(len)/sqrt(2/pi) %f ; mean/mean ratio %f \n',mean(dt(:,1) )/(2*sqrt(2/pi)) /sqrt(len) , mean(dt(:,2))/sqrt(len)/sqrt(2/pi), mean(dt(:,1) ) / mean(dt(:,2)) ) ;
```

Output:

**Mean(Max - min)/sqrt(len)/(2*sqrt(2/pi)) 0.981920;** Mean(Final)/sqrt(len)/sqrt(2/pi) 0.960711 ; mean/mean ratio 2.044153

Answer (score 1):

The formula you use in your matlab program is different from the one you propose in the statments.

What you want to calculate can be derived theoretically. Let the running maximum be

$M_t = \sup_{s\in [0\ t]} W_t$

We know that pdf of $M_t$ is twice of that of $W_t$, but only defined on $[0 \ \infty)$. From this, you can calculate that

$E(M_t) = \sqrt{\frac{2t}{\pi}}$

and the running minimum is just the negative of that. Hence the formula you used in your code.

Comment: Thank you very much for your helpful answer. You right that matlab code does not check exactly the same formula which i propose. However two question arises 1) does your answer explain matab result 2) is the proposed formula true anyway

Comment: About "does your answer explain the matlab result" - I have the following question - look you write: "the running minimum is just the negative of that . Hence the formula you used" . It seems it supposes that E(Max-Min) = E(Max) - E(Min) , but that does not seems for me to be true. Because ...

Comment: How do you think about "E" - my way of thinking is "sum over trajectories", any way, in discrete case (random work) this is indeed the formally correct. So we take trajectory and calculate max-min for fixed trajectory - exactly this is done in my matlab code. It is not the same as take max, then sum over trajectories.

Comment: I am not sure my explanation is clear. But may be you catch the idea. Any way I should write a code to compare with your way of calculation - then it would be clear what I mean from the code...

Comment: Formally, let $M_t(\omega)$ be the running maximum for path $\omega$, and $\tilde M_t(\omega)$ be the running minimum,  we have $E(M_t-\tilde M_t) = E(M_t) - E(\tilde M_t)$

Comment: well may be you are right, let me think, but that formula seems contrintuitive for me. Is this formula true in discrete case for sum of two iid ? where "trajectory" is set of two points x_1 , x_1+x_2 ? so max is max(x_1,x_1+x_2) and min of that expression ... Well seems it is true just because E(a+b) =E(a)+E(b) ... well sometimes formal approach gives faster answers than "intuitive". I think a little more ...

Comment: My "counterexample" to the formula is the following -  consider random process such that trajectories may have only the following form x(n) = 0, for all "n" except only one position, at that position "trajectory" may have a value +1 or -1. with equal probability. So for time n<=K, we have only 2K trajectories. Then clearly the formula is not correct. What does it mean ? Does it mean that not all measures on trajectories corresponds to random processes in mathematical sense or something else ?

Comment: Sorry, "counterexample" is incorrect , i was keeping in mind the lim(sup-inf), but writing about E(sup-inf). So to conclude your argument perfectly explains the matlab code result. Thank you. Still I am interstring about log-log-law, but clearly my proposed is incorrect.